How to Set Div Minimum Height based off a JavaScript grid?
I'm trying to create a form that has radio dependent on other radios and I got most of the way there except for the style. I want the left-most column with the console logos to be a fixed height based on the max-content of the thumbnail grid (5x5) while also being evenly spaced (like justify-content:space-around).
For example, if you haven't clicked anything, all the titles are squished together, but when you select "Super Mario Kart" or "Mario Kart 8", it grows to the 5x5 grid specified in JS.


`
            <div class="Console">
                <div class="console-column">
                    <label>
                        <input type="radio" name="console" value="SNES" onclick="snesCourses();">
                        <div class="console-image">
                            <img src="./images/logos/Super-Mario-Kart.png" alt="Super Mario Kart">
                        </div>
                    </label>
                    <label>
                        <input type="radio" name="console" value="N64" onclick="n64Courses();">
                        <div class="console-image">
                            <img src="./images/logos/Mario-Kart-64.png" alt="Mario Kart 64">
                        </div>
                    </label>
                    <label>
                        <input type="radio" name="console" value="GBA" onclick="gbaCourses();">
                        <div class="console-image">
                            <img src="./images/logos/Mario-Kart-Super-Circuit.png" alt="Mario Kart Super Circuit">
                        </div>
                    </label>
                    <label>
                        <input type="radio" name="console" value="GCN" onclick="gcnCourses();">
                        <div class="console-image">
                            <img src="./images/logos/Mario-Kart-Double-Dash.png" alt="Mario Kart Double Dash">
                        </div>
                    </label>
                    <label>
                        <input type="radio" name="console" value="DS" onclick="dsCourses();">
                        <div class="console-image">
                            <img src="./images/logos/Mario-Kart-DS.png" alt="Mario Kart DS">
                        </div>
                    </label>
                    <label>
                        <input type="radio" name="console" value="Wii" onclick="wiiCourses();">
                        <div class="console-image">
                            <img src="./images/logos/Mario-Kart-Wii.png" alt="Mario Kart Wii">
                        </div>
                    </label>
                    <label>
                        <input type="radio" name="console" value="3DS" onclick="mk7Courses();">
                        <div class="console-image">
                            <img src="./images/logos/Mario-Kart-7.png" alt="Mario Kart 7">
                        </div>
                    </label>
                    <label>
                        <input type="radio" name="console" value="Tour" onclick="tourCourses();">
                        <div class="console-image">
                            <img src="./images/logos/Mario-Kart-Tour.png" alt="Mario Kart Tour">
                        </div>
                    </label>
                    <label>
                        <input type="radio" name="console" value="MK8" onclick="mk8Courses();">
                        <div class="console-image">
                            <img src="./images/logos/Mario-Kart-8.png" alt="Mario Kart 8">
                        </div>
                    </label>
                    <label>
                        <input type="radio" name="console" value="Booster Courses" onclick="boosterCourses();">
                        <div class="console-image">
                            <img src="./images/logos/Mario-Kart-8-Deluxe-Booster-Course-Pass.png" alt="Mario Kart 8 Deluxe Booster Courses">
                        </div>
                    </label>
                </div>
            </div>

body {
    display: grid; 
    grid-template-columns: 66% 33%; 
    grid-template-rows: 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr; 
    gap: 1% 1%; 
    grid-template-areas: 
        "Header Header"
        "Nav Nav"
        "Settings Settings"
        "Course Stats"
        "Footer Footer";
    height: 100vh;
}

.hide {
    display: none;
}

input[type="radio"]{
    display: none;
}

h1 {
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 16px;
}
.Header { 
    grid-area: Header; 
    background: teal;
}
.Nav { 
    grid-area: Nav; 
    background: salmon;
}
.Settings { 
    grid-area: Settings; 
    background: yellowgreen;
}
.Course {
    display: grid; 
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr; 
    grid-template-rows: 10% repeat(3, minmax(1, 1fr)); 
    gap: 5% 5%; 
    grid-template-areas: 
        ". . . Class Class"
        "Console Thumbnail Thumbnail Thumbnail Thumbnail"
        "Console Thumbnail Thumbnail Thumbnail Thumbnail"
        "Console Thumbnail Thumbnail Thumbnail Thumbnail"; 
    grid-area: Course; 
    background: brown;
    gap: var(--gap);
}
.Console {
    grid-area: Console;
    border: 5px solid #000000;
    border-radius: 10px;
    align-content: center;
}
.Class { 
    grid-area: Class; 
    background: blue;
}
.Thumbnail { 
    grid-area: Thumbnail; 
    background: purple;
    border: 5px solid #000000;
    border-radius: 10px;
}
.Stats { 
    grid-area: Stats; 
    background: orange;
}
.Footer { 
    grid-area: Footer; 
    background: green;
}

/* Console Header */
.console-column {
    display: table;
    height: auto;
}

.console-image img {
    cursor: pointer;
    display: block;
    opacity: 50%;
    transition: transform 250ms ease-in-out;
    max-width: 70%;
    max-height: 10%;
    margin: auto;

    &:hover {
        opacity: 80%;
        transition: opacity 250ms ease-in-out;
    }
}

.console-column input[type=radio]:checked + .console-image img{
    opacity: 100%;
    transform: scale(1.1);
    filter: drop-shadow(0px 0px 10px hsla(0, 0%, 0%, 0.75));
    transition: transform 250ms ease-in-out, filter 250ms ease-in-out;
}

/* Course Grid */
.course-container {
    display: flex;
}

.course-thumbnail img {
    cursor: pointer;
    display: block;
    opacity: 80%;
    max-width: 90%;
    transition: transform 250ms ease-in-out;
    border: 5px solid transparent;
    margin: 5% auto;

    &:hover {
        opacity: 100%;
        transition: opacity 250ms ease-in-out;
    }
}

.course-grid input[type=radio]:checked + .course-thumbnail img{
    border: 5px solid salmon;
    background-color: salmon;
    opacity: 100%;
    mask-image: linear-gradient(135deg, transparent 5px, gold 0),
                linear-gradient(-135deg, transparent 5px, gold 0),
                linear-gradient(45deg, transparent 5px, gold 0),
                linear-gradient(-45deg, transparent 5px, gold 0);
    mask-position: 0 0, 100% 0, 0 100%, 100% 100%;
    mask-repeat: no-repeat;
    mask-size: 51% 51%;
} 

function snesCourses(){ 
  document.getElementById('snesCourses').style.display = 'grid';
  document.getElementById('snesCourses').style.gridTemplateColumns = "repeat(5, 1fr)"; 
  document.getElementById('snesCourses').style.gridTemplateRows = "repeat(5, 1fr)"; 
  document.getElementById('mk8Courses').style.display = 'none';
}

function n64Courses(){ 
  document.getElementById('snesCourses').style.display = 'none';
  document.getElementById('mk8Courses').style.display = 'none';
}

function mk8Courses(){ 
  document.getElementById('snesCourses').style.display = 'none';
  document.getElementById('mk8Courses').style.display = 'grid';
  document.getElementById('mk8Courses').style.gridTemplateColumns = "repeat(5, 1fr)"; 
  document.getElementById('mk8Courses').style.gridTemplateRows = "repeat(5, 1fr)"; 
}

Here is a CodePen example and the full project GitHub.
I know I have to change min-height of .course-container to something, I just don't know what.

First, you say you feel the need of adjusting .course-container, but you only included the CSS directives for it, and not the HTML markup, so we don't where it is. At first glance, analyzing your HTML sample, I would be tempted to say you should set .console-column instead, but I might be wrong.
As for the fix, we have one of two scenarios: either you generate the thumbnail grid dynamically, and will never know for sure what height it will have until you fill it, or you have fixed values for your thumbnail grid, and then you always know the exact height it's going to have.
If you rely on dynamic generation, after everything is loaded, you should execute:
document.getElementById('container-column').style.minHeight = document.getElementById('thumbnail-grid').offsetHeight;

If, on the contrary, the height is always the same, then you can set it directly within the CSS:
.container-column {
    min-height: [your value here]
}

You didn't include the HTML markup for the thumbnail grid, so I don't have the way to compute it myself. To figure it out, load a full thumbnail grid, and once it's loaded, then the console will be your friend:
console.log(document.getElementById('thumbnail-grid').offsetHeight);

EDIT:
Analyzing the Github repository you mentioned, I see that height of <div class='Console'> is already set. Now, if what you want is to evenly vertically space the label elements inside <div id='console-column'>, then it's just a matter of setting your CSS as so:
#console-column {
    /* Change HEIGHT from INHERIT to 100%
    height: inherit; */
    height: 100%;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    flex: 1;
    flex-basis: 100%;
    /* Add JUSTIFY-CONTENT */
    justify-content: space-around;
}


I was able to get somewhere with this but quickly ran into a deadend and had to start from the top again. I added the GitHub repository to the original post, if that helps.

@PsychedelicSeal I just edited the answer. See if this suits your needs.
